# JBoss Arquillian integration with Apache Ant and Junit

Tags: unit-testing, ant, jboss, junit, junit4

Has anyone managed to integrate Arquillian with Ant and JUnit?  If so, could you provide an example?

Comment: There is something here in the form of a gist, but is not an easy out of the box solution. https://jira.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-13

Answer (score 2):

I've prepared a draft of the build integration chapter for Arquillian. This chapter describes how you can use different build systems (namely Ant and Gradle) to drive Arquillian-based test. We'll get this rolled into the next release.

[Arquillian build integration chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/reference/snapshot/en-US/html/build.integration.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting article that discusses exactly this is this one:

[Integration testing using Arquillian without Maven](http://jdevelopment.nl/java/integration-testing-arquillian-maven/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working showcase for ant/gradle https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-showcase/tree/master/cdi